# Firefox and chrome font problem

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, fonts

I use Chrome and Firefox in my ubuntu 16.04 desktop. I face the same font problem where the text is displayed as boxes with numbers in both the browsers as shown in the attached screenshots. How to make them display actual text fonts?

[image: Firefox screenshot1]

[image: Firefox screenshot2]

Comment: in Mozilla try this going to *Cuztomize* in *Preferences* tab there you'll see *text encoding* drag it to your toolbar and save it and now try to go to a page where you don't see texts and click on *text encoding* icon and choose *unicode*. Does it do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to need some Indic fonts. To install them from a terminal window:

```
sudo apt install fonts-indic
```

Comment: Now its changed to one of my regional languages as shown in the screenshot. But I need them in English at google.co.in as before. [Firefox  Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hzzbP0ZuHDKWkruArY-uvq1VN57BuqtD). This problem occurs in both chrome and firefox.

Comment: @Gautham: You'd better ask Google about how their service works. I'm not sure, but there is a section with "Region Settings" at *Settings -> Search settings*.